# How to subset a list and remove empty vectors?

Tags: r

```
require(plyr)

list <- list(a=c(1:3),
             b=c(1:5),
             c=c(1:8),
             d=c(1:10))

llply(list,function(x)(subset(x,subset=(x>5))))
```

The above returns:

```
$a
integer(0)

$b
integer(0)

$c
[1] 6 7 8

$d
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

How to return a list only with the existing values, here $c and $d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't call a list  variable "list" as it's a function name. If it's called L then:

```
L[lapply(L,length)>0]
```

this should give a nonempty list

Answer (score 1):

You don't need **plyr** for this:

```
out <- lapply(list, function(x) x[ x > 5 ] )
out[ sapply(out, length) > 0 ]
```

Result:

```
$c
[1] 6 7 8

$d
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Arguably don't use `subset` either... `lapply( list , function(x) x[ x > 5 ] )`

Comment: @SimonO101 Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'lengths()':

```
# Your original list
your_list1 <- list(a=c(1:3),
                   b=c(1:5),
                   c=c(1:8),
                   d=c(1:10))

# Your subseted list
your_list2 <- lapply(your_list1,function(x) x[ x > 5 ])

# Your 'non_empty_elements' list    
your_final_list <- your_list2[(lengths(your_list2) > 0)]


> your_final_list
$c
[1] 6 7 8

$d
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Pdt: Names assigned to objets that you create must make sense to you, but I agree Stephen Henderson that it's not a good practice to use a functions' name for objects. I think it is not necessary either, to use such long names as I have, except for pedagogical reasons.